# Can't reference layout object by ID in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I am trying to create a custom object adapter, and part of the code require referencing object by their ID.  However, I am getting error saying the ID does not exist:

```
private static class GeoAreaAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
    private int resource;
    private GeoArea _myGeoArea;
public GeoAreaAdapter(Context context, int resource, GeoArea myGeoArea) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    _myGeoArea = myGeoArea;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout GeoAreaView;
    if (GeoAreaView == null) { 
        GeoAreaView = new LinearLayout(mInflater.getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)mInflater.getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, GeoAreaView, true);
    }
    else {
        GeoAreaView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGeoAreaName);
    name.setText(_myGeoArea.name);

    return convertView;
}
....
}
```

It happen with "R.id.txtGeoAreaName".

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtGeoAreaName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So as you can see, "txtGeoAreaName" is definitely defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inflate your layout this way:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutid, null);
```

and then you can find views:

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.someid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "txtGeoAreaName" as the id attribute of TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtGeoAreaName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update the getView method as follows

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    if (convertView == null) { 
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(resource, GeoAreaView, true);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGeoAreaName);
    name.setText(_myGeoArea.name);
    return convertView;
}
```

Also, you must use [Holder Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) to reuse the views for better performance of ListView.